# Remove bad quality pixels from daily PROBA-V images

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, data-quality, proba-v

In a previous [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460712/download-all-images-for-a-particular-month-of-a-year-in-google-earth-engine/460766#460766) of mine, I exported all images from PROBA-V satellite for a particular month without removing the bad quality pixels. Now I want to remove the bad quality pixels before exporting the images but I don't know how to write the code.

Below, I created a var called `mask_vnpa2_img` in order to set the bits according to the bit mask (called SM) ([here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/VITO_PROBAV_C1_S1_TOC_100M) is the PROBA-V product) but I can't figure out how to incorporate it into the code:

```
Map.centerObject(table);

// Here I'm trying to set the Bits according to table 'Bitmask for QF_Cloud_Mask'
var mask_vnpa2_img = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('SM');
  var CloudIceShadowFlag = bitwiseExtract(qa, 0, 2)
  var LandSea = bitwiseExtract(qa, 3)

  var mask = ee.Image(1)
    .and(CloudIceShadowFlag.eq(0)) // Clear sky conditions
    .and(LandSea.eq(1)) // Land pixels
    
      return image.updateMask(mask);
};

//Map.addLayer(table);
Map.centerObject(table);

// Project the image to Mollweide.
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';

var proj_mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);

var era5_2mt = ee.ImageCollection('VITO/PROBAV/C1/S1_TOC_100M')
                   .select('NDVI')
                   .filterDate('2018-02-01', '2018-03-01')
                   // clip to your study area
                   .map(function(image) {return image.clip(table)});

var study_area = era5_2mt.map(function(img){

  var s_ts = img.get("system:time_start");    // get the 'system:time start' property from the image

  img = ee.Image(img)
                .subtract(20)
                .divide(250)
                .set("system:time_start", s_ts)
                .set('fileName', ee.String('image_').cat(ee.Date(s_ts).format().slice(0,10)));

  return(img);
  
});

print(study_area);

// Function to export an image to Google Drive
var exportImage = function(image, fileName) {
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: fileName,
    folder: 'GEE_exports',
    scale: 100,
    region: table,
    fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
  });
};

//print(monthlyLAI.aggregate_array('fileName'))

study_area.aggregate_array('fileName').evaluate(function (fileNames) {
  fileNames.forEach(function(fileName) {
    var image = study_area
      .filter(ee.Filter.eq('fileName', fileName))
      .first();
    Map.addLayer(image, {}, fileName, false);
    exportImage(image, fileName);
  });
});
```

[Here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/nikostziokas/bangkok_54009) is the shapefile I'm using and the [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6019ec8f651ffa75948f9de5c9b9c991).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the `mask_vnpa2_img()` function to the image collection and select the NDVI band after mapping. The `bitwiseExtract()` function was missing in your code, I added it.

```
var bitwiseExtract = function(input, fromBit, toBit) {
   if (toBit === undefined) toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return input.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}
var mask_vnpa2_img = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('SM');
  var CloudIceShadowFlag = bitwiseExtract(qa, 0, 2)
  var LandSea = bitwiseExtract(qa, 3)

  var mask = ee.Image(1)
    .and(CloudIceShadowFlag.eq(0)) // Clear sky conditions
    .and(LandSea.eq(1)) // Land pixels
      return image.updateMask(mask);
};


var era5_2mt = ee.ImageCollection('VITO/PROBAV/C1/S1_TOC_100M')
                   .filterDate('2018-02-01', '2018-03-01')
                    // CHANGE HERE 
                   .map(function(image) {return mask_vnpa2_img(image).select('NDVI').clip(table)});
```

Comment: I receive the following error: `Line 65: User-defined methods must return a value.` Here is the code after your modifications (https://code.earthengine.google.com/2973258deb84e2f9a027f937ffcb03bf)

Comment: @Nikos use return in the line, it is in my the code.